# Fatal signal 11

Tags: java, android, webview, jsoup, android-asynctask

Ловлю ошибку "Fatal signal 11" причем только когда открываю ссылку которая содержит видео. В чем может быть проблема?

Ошибка:

```
02-25 22:46:09.083 4285-4715/com.example.worker.webparsing I/QCNEA: |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname www.youtube.com servname NULL numeric 0 appname 
02-25 22:46:09.333 4285-4715/com.example.worker.webparsing I/QCNEA: |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname www.youtube.com servname NULL numeric 4 appname 
02-25 22:46:09.593 4285-4713/com.example.worker.webparsing A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), thread 4713 (WebViewCoreThre)
02-25 22:46:10.294 4738-4738/com.example.worker.webparsing E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-25 22:46:10.374 4738-4755/com.example.worker.webparsing I/QCNEA: |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname fratria.ru servname NULL numeric 4 appname 
02-25 22:46:10.374 4738-4755/com.example.worker.webparsing I/QCNEA: |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname fratria.ru servname NULL numeric 0 appname 
02-25 22:46:10.404 4738-4738/com.example.worker.webparsing D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-25 22:46:10.404 4738-4738/com.example.worker.webparsing D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-25 22:46:10.414 4738-4738/com.example.worker.webparsing D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
```

Активити:

```
public class DescriptionActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mFullscreenViewCallback;
private FrameLayout mFullScreenContainer;
private View mFullScreenView;
private WebView mWebView;

private static final int SUCCESS = 1;
private static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 2;
private static final int ERROR = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mFullScreenContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_container);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    new getHtml().execute();
}

private class getHtml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    Elements tfa;
    Element title;
    String titles;
    String cop;
    Elements comments;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DescriptionActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            Uri urls = getIntent().getData();
            String url = urls.toString();

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(10000)
                    .get();

            title = doc.select(".c1-post h2").first();
            titles=title.toString().replace("img", "imgs");

            try {
                Elements link = doc.select(".imgleft img[src]");
                String imageUrl = link.attr("src");
                imageUrl = "http://fratria.ru/download" + imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.indexOf("download") + 8);

                tfa = link.attr("src", imageUrl);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            tfa = doc.select(".c1-post-data");
            cop = tfa.toString().replaceFirst("<br>©", "©").replace("style", "");
            comments = doc.select(".comments").select(".comments-heading");

            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("Unknown Host Exception", "Network error", e);
            return NETWORK_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO Exception", "Failed to load HTML", e);
            return ERROR;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "An exception occured", e);
            return ERROR;
        }
    }

    private String populateHTML(int resourceID) {
        String html;
        html = readTextFromResource(resourceID);
        html = html.replace("_TITLE_", titles);
        html = html.replace("_CONTENT_", cop);
        return html;
    }

    private String readTextFromResource(int resourceID) {
        InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i;
        try {
            i = raw.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                stream.write(i);
                i = raw.read();
            }
            raw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if (result == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Ошибка сетевого подключения. Проверьте соединение с интернетом и попробуйте снова.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Не известная ошибка. Загрузка прервана.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 1) {

            mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://fratria.ru/","<!DOCTYPE HTML>"
                    + populateHTML(R.raw.html), "text/html", "en_US", null);
        }

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
    mWebView.resumeTimers();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
    mWebView.pauseTimers();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    mWebView.stopLoading();
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(null);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(null);
    mWebView.destroy();
    mWebView = null;
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

private final WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        onShowCustomView(view, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        if (mFullScreenView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }

        mFullScreenView = view;
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mFullScreenContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mFullScreenContainer.addView(view);
        mFullscreenViewCallback = callback;
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();
        if (mFullScreenView == null) {
            return;
        }
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mFullScreenContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mFullScreenContainer.removeView(mFullScreenView);
        mFullscreenViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        mFullScreenView = null;
    }
};
```

}

Comment: А что на другом девайсе с другой версией Андроида (желательно до L)? Похоже на ошибку в нативном плагине, который WebView пытается вызвать.

Comment: Такое на 4.2.2. пробовал на 4.1.2. подобных проблем нет.

Comment: А производитель девайсов кто?

Comment: Гусары не ржать. Yota Device :))))))

Comment: :) Так попробуйте как каком-то другом производителе.